# How to have an emoji as a button with listener

Tags: android, button, emoji

I want to open a Dialouge as soon as i press an emoji button, how could I add such a button in Android Studio, is there a possible library to do this? also possibly add ripple effect etc. I want the button to just be an emoji, meaning that there must not be any emojis as text on button (only if it's possible to have the moji occupy the entire view).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the emoji you want from here:
https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

And replace '**U+**' to '**0x**'

***U+1F60A*** to ***0x1F60A***

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
emojiButton.setText(new String(Character.toChars(unicode)));
```

About the ripple effect:

If you use *android.widget.Button*, it already has ripple effect by default. 
But if you use anything else, you need this:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

or if you want circle ripple effect:

```
android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

Comment: what button are you using in this example?, is it something native, a library, or androids emojibutton?

Comment: It is the native. (android.widget.Button) I think you can use this solution with any button library which includes text.

Comment: Yes, but it wont allow me to have the button be only the emoji, and not an emoji on a button (button being gray in android's case)

Comment: It's the code you posted above, it is showing me a button with an emoji on it, but i want to add a button, which is only the emoji and no border around it, by using the code above you will get a gray button, with an emoji in the centre

Comment: It has to be just the emoji and nothing else

Comment: in the layout file add this line to your button.android:background="@android:color/transparent"